# iOS17 and WidgetConfiguration with custom AppEntity types

Tags: xcode, swiftui, widget, ios17, appintents

we're trying to take advantage of the new iOS17 interactive widgets feature. To do that, we need to properly configure a Widget, using some sort of widgetMode that, in turns, is bind to specific parameters that should appear only for some modes.

To do that, we crafter a custom AppEntity type as follow:

```
struct WidgetMode: AppEntity, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    static var defaultQuery = WidgetQuery()

    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = TypeDisplayRepresentation(name: LocalizedStringResource("Mode"))

    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        switch id {
        case 0:
            return DisplayRepresentation(title: LocalizedStringResource("Favorites"))
        case 1:
            return DisplayRepresentation(title: LocalizedStringResource("Recents"))
        case 2:
            return DisplayRepresentation(title: LocalizedStringResource("Categories"))
        case 3:
            return DisplayRepresentation(title: LocalizedStringResource("Collections"))
        default:
            return DisplayRepresentation(title: LocalizedStringResource("Unknown"))
        }
    }

    static func == (lhs: WidgetMode, rhs: WidgetMode) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

struct WidgetQuery: EntityQuery {
    func entities(for identifiers: [Int]) async throws -> [WidgetMode] {
        [0, 1, 2, 3].map({ WidgetMode(id: $0)})
    }
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [WidgetMode] {
        [0, 1, 2, 3].map({ WidgetMode(id: $0)})
    }
}
```

Then taking advantage of the new ParameterSummary feature, we're trying to manipulate the output input parameters, according to specific modes:

```
struct ConfigurationAppIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Configuration"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Choose what to show")

    @Parameter(title: LocalizedStringResource("Show"))
    var widgetMode: WidgetMode

    @Parameter (title: "Category")
    var category: CategoryDetail?

    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        When(\.$widgetMode, .equalTo, WidgetMode(id: 2)) {
            Summary {
                \.$widgetMode
                \.$category
            }
        } otherwise: {
            Summary {
                \.$widgetMode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, **When** clausole seems to ignore at all the **.equalTo** condition, falling back always on **otherwise** branch.

Changing the widgetMode, just for test, with a simple **Bool** or an **Int** seems to work quite well.

So, is there any limitation that we are not aware of about using AppEntity and ParameterSummary? Is there anything wrong in my implementation? Could be a bug on current iOS17 / Xcode (we're on stable channel, yet).

Many thanks for any response and/or feedback in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in iOS 17 (FB13263902). As a workaround, one can base the AppEnum on a `String` instead of an `Int`. Then the bug is not triggered:

```
enum WidgetMode: String, CaseIterable, AppEnum, Equatable {
    static let title = LocalizedStringResource("")

    case one, two, three

    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = TypeDisplayRepresentation(name: LocalizedStringResource("Mode"))

    static var caseDisplayRepresentations: [WidgetMode: DisplayRepresentation] = [
        .one: DisplayRepresentation(title: LocalizedStringResource("Option One")),
        .two: DisplayRepresentation(title: LocalizedStringResource("Option Two")),
        .three: DisplayRepresentation(title: LocalizedStringResource("Option Three")),
    ]
}

struct ConfigurationAppIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Configuration"
    static var description = IntentDescription("This is an example widget.")

    @Parameter(title: LocalizedStringResource("Show"))
    var widgetMode: WidgetMode

    @Parameter(title: "Favorite Emoji", default: "")
    var favoriteEmoji: String


    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        When(\.$widgetMode, .equalTo, .three) {
            Summary {
                \.$widgetMode
                \.$favoriteEmoji
            }
        } otherwise: {
            Summary {
                \.$widgetMode
            }
        }
    }
}
```